# Proving convergence by the comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

I need to prove the convergence of the following series :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}$$

I suppose I need to find two series like
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(k_1a_n + k_2b_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} = k_1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n  + k_2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$$

I thought that the series $a_n$ and $b_n$ can be the partial sums, so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)} =  \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n+1)} - \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n-2)}$$

I know, by the comparison test, that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge, the main series will it too. But, how can I demonstrate that the series $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge?

Comment: Your partial fraction step is wrong. It should be a minus instead of a plus and neither $a_n$ nor $b_n$ converges.

Comment: telescopi rule$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)} = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{(3n-2)} + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n+1)}$$

Comment: For completeness on this question, we should note that the two sums $a_n$ and $b_n$ do _not_ converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\ge 1$, $3n+1>n$ and for $n\ge 2$, we have $3n-2>n$.  Hence,
$$\frac1{(3n-2)(3n+1)}<\frac1{n^2},\quad \text{for }n\ge 2.$$

Comment: good ol' $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

Answer (score 6):

One may just observe a telescoping sum here

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}=\frac13\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{3(n-1)+1}-\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)=\frac13-\frac{1}{3(3N+1)}
> $$

giving the **convergence** and the **sum** of your initial series.

Comment: This is of course a nice answer.  Probably one should include the comments that (i) it does not use the comparison test and (ii) it is somewhat "lucky" that it turns out to be a telescoping su can be mevaluated exactly.  The larger class of series of the form $\sum_n \frac{ f(n)}{g(n)}$ for polynomials $f$ and $g$ which can be evaluated using the comparison test and the "$p$-series test", and very rarely by a telescoping sum.